# How to find whether a string not surrounded by <a> tag

Tags: html, regex

How to create a regular expression for the string which is not surrounded by anchor tag (a)

for example :

```
this is <a href="#">sample link</a> this is sample link testing.
```

This line consist of 2 "sample link" but I need to get only second "sample link" which is not surrounding by (anchor) tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

 $dom = new DOMDocument();
    //here goes the content even the links also you can have in your content 
    $content = 'this is <a href="#">sample link</a> this is sample link testing is sample link testing
        is sample link testing is sample link testing is sample link <a href="#">sample link</a> testing labs
        hello extended and link behave as if soon and post';


    $dom->loadHtml($content);
    $xml = simplexml_import_dom($dom);
    $data  = $xml->xpath('//body');
    $link  = $xml->xpath('//body/p/a');

    $resultLink = preg_split("/".$link[0][0]."/",$content, -1, PREG_SPLIT_OFFSET_CAPTURE);

    foreach($resultLink as $key=>$value):

        echo $resultLink[$key][0]."<a href='sample.html'>".$link[0][0]."</a>";

    endforeach;
?>
```

Comment: Arul, Thanks for your reply. but my requirement is not to remove html tags. Actually I need to make "sample link" text to a link. for this i have created a regular expression. But if some "sample link" are link already then I have to avoid this.

Comment: so if a string contains "sample link" in 10 places ,,all the 10 places should have a anchor tag right

Comment: No. For example : if 2 "sample link" out of 10 have anchor tag and 8 have not, Then I have to find only 8 "sample link" and then add anchor tag to them.

Comment: @subu.purohit check out the post now and give me an up vote thnks.

Comment: Hi Sam, in your example 1 "sample link" is mission and 1 link is added to last of string.

Comment: can we have a chat instead of this discussion?

Comment: you r having only 6 reputation ,come to gmail chat ping me samarulraj@gmail.com